# git format-patch fatal: ambiguous argument

Tags: git, branch, patch

I have a branch, branding, that branches from branch `v8.2.3` (which is also a tag at the branch point) I want to make a patch of the branding branch to move it to a later version but git says the branch name is ambiguous and will not create a patch.

I wonder is this because the version branch name is the same as the tag?

[image: gitk display, git command and error]

Comment: It appears to simply be a typo. According to your screenshot of `gitk`, the name of the tag is `v8.2.3`, but you wrote `v.8.2.3` (note the extra period after the "v") in your command: `git format-patch v.8.2.3 --stdout > branding.patch`. The error message reads "unknown revision [...]"; that should have given you a hint about the cause of the error.

Comment: @Jubobs thanks. That reduced the error to `Warning: refname 'v8.2.3' is ambiguous` Is there any way I can tell it that it should use the tag name, or use the branch name? (they're both at the same point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your command contains a typo. According to your screenshot of `gitk`, the name of the tag is `v8.2.3`, but you wrote `v.8.2.3` (note the extra period after the "v") in your command:

   ```
   git format-patch v.8.2.3 --stdout > branding.patch
   ```

   The error message reads

   > [...] unknown revision [...]

   That should have given you a hint about the cause of the error.
2. You have both a branch and a tag called `v8.2.3`. This is problematic because, wherever you don't use a "fully qualified" `v8.2.3` reference in a Git command, Git will understand that reference as the tag. If you want to refer to the branch of the same name, you need to specify `res/heads/v8.2.3` instead. You should endeavour using distinct names for your tags and branches. Run

   ```
   git branch -m v8.2.3 <new-branch-name>
   ```

   to rename the branch, where `<new-branch-name>` stands for a more appropriate branch name.

Comment: Branch name is out of my control unfortunately, but thanks for the advice. The `refs/heads/v8.2.3` is handy to know instead of finding and using the hash

Comment: "In the red corner we have Jubobs, in the blue, codeWizard, this is Mortal Combat, FIGHT!" ;)

Comment: @Toby *You must do what you feel is right, of course.*

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a type.

You have an extra `.` between the v and the 8

Your tag name is `v8.2.3` white l=in the LCI you are referring to it as `v.8.2.3`

In git branches, tags, HEAD etc are simply references to a given commit. When you use any of them git simply translate to to the given commit and use the SHA-1.

Since you have `typo`git can find out the SHA-1 so it display the error.

For example: view the content of the `.git/ref/head/mastar` and you will see the SHA-1 inside like in any other tag, branch etc.

Comment: Thanks. That reduced the error to `Warning: refname 'v8.2.3' is ambiguous` Is there any way I can tell it that it should use the tag name, or use the branch name? (they're both at the same point)

Comment: Find the sha-1 of the tag/branch whatever you want and use it.

Comment: Use the `git describe `